# How can I know what is causing a null pointer in my entity class getTeamId

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null

I have tried to understand what is causing my getTeamId() method in my entity return null, but I can't seem to crack the code. I have attached my adapter class, entity class and the exception thrown.

```
    Entity Class TeamEntity
 @SerializedName("idTeam")
    private String teamId;
        public String getTeamId() {
            return teamId;
        }

        public void setTeamId(String teamId) {
            this.teamId = teamId;
    }
```

And in my adapter class I have the following, it says team is null do i need to add something to it?

```
public class MatchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private TeamEntity team;
    private List<MatchEntity> matchList;

    public MatchAdapter(Context context, TeamEntity teamEntity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.team = teamEntity;
        matchList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setList(List<MatchEntity> matchList) {
        this.matchList.addAll(matchList);
        Collections.sort(this.matchList); //date order
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateMatch(MatchEntity match) {
        matchList.set(matchList.indexOf(match), match);
        notifyItemChanged(matchList.indexOf(match));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.display_match_items, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MatchEntity match = matchList.get(position);
        holder.bind(match);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return matchList.size();
    }
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MatchEntity match = matchList.get(position);
    holder.bind(match);
}

     void bind(MatchEntity match) {

                String homeTeam = match.getHomeTeam() != null ? match.getHomeTeam() : "";


                if (team.getTeamId().equals(match.getIdGuestTeam())) {
                    homeTextView.setText(homeTeam);


                } else {
                    homeTextView.setText(guestTeam);

                }
```

// Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.sportsapp.data.room.entities.TeamEntity.getTeamId()' on a null object reference
        at com.sportsapp.presentation.ui.adapters.MatchAdapter$ViewHolder.bind(MatchAdapter.java:118)
        at com.sportsapp.presentation.ui.adapters.MatchAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MatchAdapter.java:59)
        at com.sportsapp.presentation.ui.adapters.MatchAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MatchAdapter.java:27)
```

Comment: `team` is `null`. It is unclear where `team` comes from. You might consider posting the entire adapter class.

Comment: `team` must be `null` when you call your `MatchAdapter` constructor.

Comment: Congratulations on using java 14 which gives you a readable explanation on what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing to teamEntity?

```
public MatchAdapter(Context context, TeamEntity teamEntity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.team = teamEntity;
        matchList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: The matchList which is an ArrayList